# Patching Azure IAAS Windows Machines

Tags: windows, patch

I want a automated way where i want to apply patches for my Azure IAAS VMs. Could some one please help me with the best ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you mean by automated. If you never want to do anything at all, you need to move from IaaS to PaaS and let Microsoft/Azure deal with it. Otherwise you need to look at deploying WSUS (or similar) or integrating your subscription with OMS so you can push patches out from there.